# CNN Go on Ubunu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, browser

I am using CNN Go to watch streamed news.  However, it does not work with neither Opera, Chrome, nor Firefox.  I am not using any sort of proxy or VPN.

Does anyone else have the same issue?  The URL is use is

http://go.cnn.com/

It never gets past this:

[image]

Comment: do you have flash installed?

Comment: Well, Firefox has Shockwave Flash.  And Chrome has Flash.  I verified by following these instructions:
https://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/kb/enable-flash-player-google-chrome.html

Comment: hmm it happens for me to. If you do Ctrl+Shift+K in Firefox you can see some erros but I'm not sure what's causing them.

Comment: I did some googling, and found someone who suggested that I fake my user-agent.  I changed it to MSIE and Windows via a Chrome plugin, but that did not help.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix the issue by installing 'hal'. This doesn't come standard with 16.04 so you have to add a ppa:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mjblenner/ppa-hal
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install hal
```

Close browser and reopen.

**additional information:**

*https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HAL_(software)*

*https://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/kb/flash-player-11-problems-playing.html*

Comment: Installing more outdated software feels kinda wrong, how did you know that you have to look for HAL? Since their website gives the impression that it's cross-device compatible and works on iDevices, seeing a Flash-based solution is sad.

Comment: Watching cnn feels kind of wrong. lol. But yeah I searched common problems with flash on ubuntu and found the hal issue.